# Railsのsubmitの2重送信を避ける方法disable_withの書き方がネット上に2パターンあるがどこかのバージョンで仕様変更がありましたか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsの`submit`に付与する`disable_with`ですが

`submit(data: {disable_with: "文字"})`
の形と
`submit(disable_with: "文字")`
の2パターンをネット上で見かけるのですが、どこかのバージョンで仕様が変わりましたでしょうか？Rails4だと前者が正しいと考えています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.2.4 と、

[rails/CHANGELOG.md at 3-2-stable · rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/CHANGELOG.md#rails-324-may-31-2012)

> Deprecate :disable_with in favor of 'data-disable-with' option for button_to, button_tag and submit_tag helpers.

4.0.0 で 変更されたみたいですよ。

[rails/CHANGELOG.md at 4-0-stable · rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/CHANGELOG.md)

> Deprecate :disable_with in favor of data: { disable_with: "Text" } option from submit_tag, button_tag and button_to helpers.